# Can a question "ask" or "request," or is this an action that only humans can do?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Is it appropriate to say, for instance:

1. *This question asks for advice.*
2. *This question asks about dogs.*
3. *These questions request help.*

Or are the acts of *asking* & *requesting* actions that only humans can do?

Comment: It's a bit metaphorical and might not stand well (it's a bit pleonastic, the object of asking is always a question), but it's not crazy. Probably would be marked down in an English composition class, but works in everyday talk or metaphorically extenuating circumstances.

Comment: @Mitch: I find it hard to believe any teacher would be so "anal" as to object to such a commonplace usage.

Comment: In the final analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost 200,000 written instances of [this question asks](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20question%20asks%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22this%20question%20asks%22&oq=%22this%20question%20asks%22&gs_l=serp.3...5136.7850.2.8074.12.12.0.0.0.1.119.918.11j1.12.0...0.0...1c.1.18.psy-ab.1EpZm42BG-o&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.d2k&fp=340a5a63302ed31b&biw=1270&bih=930) suggest that Anglophones in general don't share OP's misgivings about the usage. You might as well ask whether questions can "suggest".

I'm not so keen on [this question requests](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20question%20asks%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22this%20question%20requests%22&oq=%22this%20question%20requests%22&gs_l=serp.3...39889.40675.1.40950.3.3.0.0.0.0.119.222.2j1.3.0...0.0...1c.1.18.psy-ab.NgayXbBOAZU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.d2k&fp=340a5a63302ed31b&biw=1270&bih=930) (with only 1880 hits, obviously nor are most others). The assonance sounds clumsy to me, but it smacks more of tautology than undue anthropomorphism.

Comment: If wine can drink well, surely questions can ask well — and answer. :)

Comment: @tchrist: [This guy](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sentence+this+book+reads+well%22) says he found it *hard to say whether [CULD](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/) actually accounts for the sentence **This (book) reads well**.* Apparently, according to their description of the construction, it should be *This book reads **good***. But I couldn't be doing with *This question asks good* any more than *It asks well*.

Answer (score 1):

In those formulations, I would say the phrasing is strange. What you *could* say is that:

- The question demands to be answered
- The question begs to be answered
- The question begs for an answer, etc.

That would be a personification, which is a stylistic device best fit for literary fiction, but not altogether wrong even in a formal context - unless you're writing a law, I suppose.

In those precise formulations, in your case, you could reword them as:

1. *This is an inquiry for advice.*
2. *This question pertains to dogs.*
3. *These questions need help.* (if what you want to convey is that they need to be corrected) or *These questions ask for help.*

The issue with the wording is that the more you go into specifics, the less you're able to "personify" the act of asking. A question can beg to be answered, but the moment you introduce a specific subject to be answered, it reads better if you de-personify the question.

A question can be curious, but it can not have its own interests.

Comment: You don't explicitly say why you find the phrasing "strange", but OP's question implies *he's* bothered about it because it seems to anthropomorphise the abstract noun *question*. But surely *begging* is at least as much a "human" activity as *asking* or *requesting*.

Comment: Read my whole post.

Comment: I'd say that 'these questions need help' is the strangest of the lot.

Comment: It is. Couldn't think of any way to make it sound more acceptable though.

Comment: 'These are questions that need answering.' However, the OP means 'These are appeals for help.'